# Explaining indeterminate forms

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

A student of mine asked me why $+\infty -\infty$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ are considered indeterminate forms.

I think that this is an only apparently stupid question. In other words how can I show, using simple arguments, that $+\infty -\infty$ isn't equal to zero and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ isn't equal to 1?

Comment: I fail to see anything apparently stupid about the question.

Comment: In the extended real numbers $\overline{\mathbb R}$, it is common to leave the expressions $+\infty-\infty$, and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ undefined. This is because the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=x-y$ cannot be continuous extended at the point $(\infty,\infty)$. Similar remarks apply to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: However, one cannot *prove* that these expressions are undefined, as this is simply a matter of mathematical convention and convenience. There is nothing incorrect about defining $\infty-\infty$ as $0$, say, but this would give $\overline{\mathbb R}$ undesirable properties, such as addition no longer being continuous wherever it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $\infty$ is not a number that you can not operate as it doesn't belong to real numbers or to any mathematical set. Mathematically $\infty$ doesn't exist. When you think of infinity you think about a number that tends to infinity. Indeed infinity doesn't exist.
However, we can deal with numbers that tend to infinity in the way that we study their behavior as they get greater. I will show an example. Take two functions:
$$f(x) = x$$
$$g(x)= e^x$$
Both functions grow indefinitely if x grows as well as both have positive derivative throughout all its domain. When we ask what $f(x)/g(x)$ will be when $x\rightarrow \infty$ (when x gets bigger and bigger) you can work out the solution with a calculator using values of x and you would get that if you make x bigger then $f(x)/g(x)$ will be $0$. However this is a limit, you are not substituting a number by infinity, you are increasing its value.

So, the result of a function tending to infinity divided by another function tending to infinity will depend on the functions you are dividing. And very important, the functions aren't infinity, you are just measuring the result of the divisions as $x$ grows.

Comment: My problem is to convince the student that reasoning with infinite quantities isn't like reasoning with finite ones. I teach in a technical high school and everybody wants to shift these concepts in a finite setting.

Comment: I would go to the root of it showing that infinity doesn't exist. Maybe you could show your students that i.e. even if they are imagining an infinite line but they will be only capable of imagining a very long one but never infinite. Maybe it is because we as humans can not deal with infinity. From my point of view, maths can only deal with what we can imagine, measure, or quantify. The main point is that in highschool someone deals with real numbers and complex ones but the laws of these numbers can not be used with non-mathematical or unimaginable concepts such as infinity.

Comment: What I mean is that they have to get clear that infinity doesn't exist, or at least from our capacities as humans.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n = 2n$ and $b_n=n$.

Obviously, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$ and  $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \infty$. By moving the limits around naively, you see that  $+ \infty - \infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n - \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n-b_n) = \infty \neq 0$.

And $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n}{\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n}= 2 \neq 1$.

**Note**: This is not intended to be rigorous, as the question was more of a *philosophical* one.